# Using Jupyter Notebook to Blender/Adobe After-Effects

Tags: python, python-3.x, blender, after-effects

I am currently using Jupyter notebook to create a program using IBM Watson Tone Analyzer service. I wanted to know if it is possible to use the notebook I'm working on to run/launch an animation I've created in something like blender or adobe aftereffects?

Comment: Jupyter notebook are more for teaching purposes I guess,
I would recommand to use proper python file, and lauch your animation from the console. It will be more flexible.